# Force a compile time error checking a templated type with a constant

Tags: c++

This is what I am trying to do:

```
#define SIZE 8

template<class T>
struct name {
    T a;
    name() {
        #if SIZE != sizeof(T)*8
        #error Size mismatch
        #endif
    }
};

int main(void)
{
    name<uint16_t> a; //Size mismatch

   return 0;
}
```

I want it to give a compile time error when the size doesn't match when using the templated struct i.e `name<uint16_t>` should give a compile time error because it doesn't comply with the requirement `(sizeof(T)*8 == 8)`.

Can this be done in `<C++11`?

Comment: boost has its own version of STATIC_ASSERT http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_staticassert.html

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ : That will probably solve my issue somehow but I found an `enable_if` implementation [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if). Usage: `template<class T, typename = typename enable_if<SIZE == sizeof( T ) * 8, T>::type> struct name ...` (I was just about to post it as an answer:D)

Answer (score 2):

You can assert it:

```
static_assert(SIZE != sizeof(T)*8, "!");
```

Your code becomes:

```
#include<cstddef>

#define SIZE 8

template<class T>
struct name {
    static_assert(SIZE != sizeof(T)*8, "!");
    T a;
};

int main(void) {
    name<uint16_t> a;
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**

This answer applies for C++11 and later.
The requirement was that when I wrote it, so I'd leave it for further readers anyway.

Comment: I would point out that this answer is C++11 and greater

Comment: @nasser-sh Isn't it what the OP asked for? He said - _Can this be done in C++11?_.

Comment: Ah! If you look at the edit history of the post, OP stated "must be in < C++11". Missed the update.

Comment: @nasser-sh Wow. Missed the original sentence. Good go!! :-D

Comment: It's `<C++11`, don't know how and in what sense someone can edit it to `C++11`

Comment: @Jahid You are confusing me. Ok, this answer applies from C++11 and later.

Comment: Well, someone mistakenly edited and removed the `<`. But your answer is a good one. I may use it (with a preprocessor guard) if I can't find any way of doing it with `<C++11`